# How to maintain the functionality of website even if server's disk space is full?

Tags: wordpress, webserver

Any website would stop functioning properly when server's disk space gets full.why?
My theory: logs creation gets affected!Also, server might need to create some temporary files,which causes slow browsing experience.

How can the functionality of website be maintained, i mean user should not experience any problem, even if the disk space is full.

Is there any wordpress specific solution available?

Disk Space will remain full, i cant help it, is there any method to reserve some space for hosting website?

Comment: If you're using a hosting website, you can use logrotate or a cleanup script or something to keep your logs a manageable size.  The typical solution is, since web servers don't typically generate a lot of persistent data, just get a disk with enough free space that you don't have to care.

Comment: the main problem is, same server is used for other project development as well, so even a use some script to clean up logs, the space will be filled by some other users. Hence this might not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was database queries gets affected if server's disk space was full,
hence the database was migrated to another server.

Caching was also implemented to improve the performance.

Also,applying  User quotas could have been a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use memcached, you can add more servers on the cluster. Memcached can be loaded on a different server. Use W3Cache Performance plugin.

Answer (score 0):

partition it properly or enforce quota. basically no modern operating system will work properly with disk totally full.